# rails simple form for nested routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form, nested-routes

I am trying to build a `simple_form_for` in Rails 3.2 for `@objects` with a doubly nested route, e.g.:

```
/users/1/projects/2/objects
```

The form is:

```
<%= simple_form_for @object, :url => user_project_objects_path(@user, @project), :html => { :class => 'form-horizontal' } do |f| %>
```

In routes.rb:

```
resources :users do
  resources :projects do
    resources :objects do
      collection { post :import }
    end
  end
end
```

My question is: what goes in the `new` and `create` action of the `Object` controller?

So far - and I am getting a routing error - I have:

```
def create
  @user = current_user
  @project = Project.find_by_user_id(@user)
  @object = @project.objects.build(params[:object])
  if @object.save
    flash[:notice] = "Object was successfully created"
    redirect_to user_project_objects_path
  else
    render 'new'
  end
end

def new
  @user = current_user
  @project = Project.find_by_user_id(@user)
  @object = @project.objects.build
end
```

Any advice is much appreciated.

#### In response to Greg W:

```
No route matches {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"objects", :user_id=>#<Object id: 8, source_lang_id: 1, source_content: "Kaffehaus", target_lang_id: 2, target_content: "cafe", domain_id: 2, owner_id: nil, created_at: "2013-01-04 06:36:55", updated_at: "2013-01-04 06:36:55", project_id: 2>}
```

The `owner_id` (User, i.e. current_user) is not being updated - and this may be the issue(?)

Comment: Can you provide the routing error? It might be a result of your url helper `user_project_objects_path` after the `redirect_to`. It likely requires an argument to specify the project id. i.e., `user_project_objects_path(@project)`.

Comment: thanks for your reply. Updated with routing error

Answer (score 5):

In the form you can use

```
simple_form_for([@user, @project, object]) do
```

You can use the relationship to fetch data like

```
@project= current_user.projects
```

instead of

```
@project = Project.find_by_user_id(@user)
```

Comment: current_user.projects would return an array of projects. I am only interested in the project I am currently in. The simple_form_for header is equivalent to the suggestion above. I believe the answer lies in how the New model builds the three instance variables and how they are updated in create Object to include the user_id and project_id in the params hash.

Answer (score 0):

I worked it out in the meantime. Perhaps this may be a usual guide to others working on a doubly nested routing such as user -> projects -> objects (has_many, has_many)

In the Object controller New action:

```
@user = current_user
@project = Project.find(params[:project_id])
@object = Object.new
```

In the Object controller Create action:

```
 @user = current_user
 @project = Project.find(params[:project_id])
 @object = @project.objects.build(params[:object])
 @object.owner_id = @user.id  #owner id maps to User
```

The routing error was a result of not specifying all objects, user, project and objects
in

```
user_project_objects_path(@project)
```